# Second @media query not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm working on a website and I want to use Media queries to change some of the css at two different screen sizes. I want the *new new css.css* to be the main css and then the rules in *medium.css* to kick in at screen widths between 955px and 650px and *small.css* to kick in at screen widths below 650px

This is links to the stylesheets in my HTML

```
<link href="new new css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 955px) and (min-width: 650px)" href="medium.css" />
<link href="small.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 650px) />
```

*The medium.css* works correctly but then below 650px, the page goes back to just using *new new css.css* and none of the rules in *small.css* apply

Answer (score 1):

You don't have closing quotes around this section:

```
type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 650px) />
```

It should be

```
type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 650px)" />
```